# Генерация HTML на основе JSON и наоборот

Tags: javascript, html, json

Есть иерархическая структура полей (`select,input`), c возможностью для пользователя объединения и вложения их друг в друга. Иначе говоря дерево логических выражений, где каждая вершина-значение - это несколько форм ввода.

Так как это дерево необходимо сохранять в некую структуру и восстанавливать обратно (строить HTML) из неё. То посоветовали использовать JSON + какую-либо JS-библиотеку, чтобы уйти от изменений кода в случае незначительных изменений формы.

HTML выглядит следующим образом (сгенерирован для примера, из HTML удалены из лишние компоненты типа кнопок):

```
    <div class="conditions-group logical-or">

<div class="conditions">

    <div class="conditions-group logical-and">

        <div class="conditions">

            <div class="condition row">
                <div class="metric">
                    <select class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="operator">
                    <select class="form-control "></select>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                    <input value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="condition row">
                <div class="metric">
                    <select class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="operator">
                    <select class="form-control "></select>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                    <input value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="condition row">
            <div class="metric">
                <select class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="operator">
                <select class="form-control "></select>
            </div>
            <div class="value">
                <input value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Блоки строятся с помощью JQuery на основе текущих.

Прошу помочь: Что поможете посоветовать для реализации такого типа задачи? Если JS-библиотека, то какая?

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: для начала предоставьте пример (дерева логических выражений) в HTML и JS